# Nginx rewrite - remove substring at the end of URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a faulty plugin that is generating URLs with /mobile at the end. I am trying to fix the plugin but in the meantime I would like to write a Nginx rewrite rule to redirect as shown below:

http://www.domain.com/article-slug/mobile

to

http://www.domain.com/article-slug/

Can some help me with coming up with the rewrite rule? I researched but could not find something that works in my case. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What doesn't work, then?

Comment: `rewrite ^(.*)mobile$ $1 break;`

Comment: Thanks. How do I write the location block with this redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite won't perform a redirect, but will do something more akin to an internal forward. Assuming you want a 301 sent, then you'd do:

```
rewrite ^(.*/)mobile$ $1 permanent;
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I write the location block with this redirect?

Comment: Well it could just be in the server block. I'm not sure what you'd need for your location block in particular, you could just put it in the "/" location if you want it there